# ACS Rule Groups: add a claim if another claim has a given value

Tags: azure, acs

Is it possible to configure ACS so that, if it receives an input claim with a specific value, it outputs that input claim with its original value together with another, completely new claim?

I'm trying to push some of my application's user profile attributes into the claims received from ACS, but so far I seem to only be able to transform a claim, which has the effect of dropping the original claim and its value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is totally possible.

The you achieve that is by first generating the default Pass-through Rules. This will effectively create your first rule - input claim to output claim with no modification.

Now you just add a new rule and define what you want it to be - inspect input claim type, its value, and finally decide what the output claim type and its value will be. You can define as many rules for a single input claim as you wish. There is no limitation for this process.

Comment: Doh!  Easy cheesey. Thanks, Anton!